# how do I fix NoReverseMatch error when i trying convert to class base my code?

Tags: python, django

I have some code and when it executes, it throws a No Reverse Match, saying:

What does this mean, and what can I do about it?

I m trying convert my code to class base and name space for my app.

I have some code and when it executes, it throws a NoReverseMatch, saying:

```
NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/leads/6/
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/leads/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$']
```

`view.py`

```
class LeadDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Lead

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AddCommentForm()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(LeadDetailView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))


class LeadDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Lead
    success_url = reverse_lazy('leads:list')

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(LeadDeleteView, self).get_queryset()
        team = self.request.user.userprofile.active_team
        return queryset.filter(team=team, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)


class LeadUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Lead
    fields = ('name', 'email', 'description', 'priority', 'status',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('leads:list')

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Edit lead'

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(UpdateView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'leads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.LeadListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.LeadDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.LeadDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', views.LeadUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/convert/', views.ConvertToClientView.as_view(), name='convert'),
    path('add/', views.LeadCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
]
```

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ lead.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="py-4 px-6">
        <h1 class="mb-4 text-xl">{{ lead.name }}</h1>

        {% if lead.description %}
            <p class="font-semibold">Description</p>
            <p class="mb-2 "> {{ lead.description }}</p>
        {% endif %}
        <p class="font-semibold">Priority</p>
        <p class="mb-2 ">{{ lead.get_priority_display }}</p>

        <p class="font-semibold">Status</p>
        <p class="mb-2 ">{{ lead.get_status_display }}</p>

        <p class="font-semibold">Created at</p>
        <p class="mb-2 ">{{ lead.created_at|date:"M-d-Y H:i" }}</p>

        <p class="font-semibold">Modified at</p>
        <p class="mb-6 ">{{ lead.modified_at }}</p>

        <hr class="my-4">

            <form id="lead_delete_form" method="post" action="{% url 'leads:delete' lead.id %}" >
             {% csrf_token %}
            </form>

            <a href="{% url 'leads:convert' lead.id %}" class="py-2 px-4 rounded-xl bg-blue-500 text-white">Convert to client</a>
            <a href="{% url 'leads:edit' lead.id %}" class="py-2 px-4 rounded-xl bg-teal-500 text-white">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('lead_delete_form').submit();" class="py-2 px-4 rounded-xl bg-red-500 text-white">Delete</a>

        <hr class="my-4">

        <h2 class="text-2xl">Comments</h2>

        <form method="get" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <button class="py-2 px-4 rounded-xl bg-blue-500 text-white">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <hr class="my-4">

        <a href="{% url 'leads:list' %}">Back to Leads</a>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `action="{% url 'leads:delete' lead.id %}"` I'm going to guess that the problem is `lead` is null, therefore the template cannot properly construct a link to the `delete` view, as the link would require an id.  How are you passing `lead` into the template context?

Comment: `DetailView` passes `object` to a template, it does not pass `lead`. You can override get_context_data and include `lead` into `context` or declare local variable in the template as lead=object.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your "urls.py" which requires the `pk` argument on delete view, the error tells you that the `pk` argument is not being passed correctly when generating the URL.

To fix this issue, you should ensure that the `pk` argument is correctly provided to the `success_url` attribute when using the `reverse` or `reverse_lazy` functions.

For example, you can update the `success_url` attribute in your `LeadDeleteView` as follows:

```py
success_url = reverse_lazy('leads:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```